# JLayeredPane for Java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, java-7, jlayeredpane

my problem currently is that I have a JFrame (with some buttons on it)...when I clicked on the "New" button, it will call an InternalFrame on the screen...the internal frame screen came out and everything is good until i move the internal frame around and found that it is set at the back of everything...

I have tried the .toFront() , .setAlwaysOnTop() and everything...until I came across the JLayeredPane and I think it is something I am looking for...but I couldn't make it work >< can anyone else guide me through it? Thanks!

[image]

Please do tell the extra information you all need..will provide them ASAP

```
WindowConstruct wconstruct;

JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
JInternalFrame InternalWindows = new JInternalFrame();

public MainUser(){

wconstruct = new WindowConstruct("..:: User's Helpdesk Main Page ::..", 1500, 800, false, null, "user");

    wconstruct.add(desktop);

    wconstruct.btnNew.addActionListener(this);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object src = e.getSource();

    if(src == wconstruct.btnNew){

        InternalWindows.setSize(500, 300);
        InternalWindows.setTitle("New task");
        InternalWindows.setLayout(null);
        InternalWindows.setLocation(100,50);
        InternalWindows.setClosable(true);

        desktop.add(InternalWindows);
        InternalWindows.setVisible(true);         

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should be adding the JInternalFrame to a `JDesktopPane`, not directly to the frame. The image you're showing is a symptom of doing the latter. See [How to use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html). Or maybe if you want the internal frame to "always be on top", you're probably looking to use a model JDialog, instead of an internal frame. See [How to use Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: I have tried JDesktopPane...but when I called the JDesktopPane...my entire system will be covered by it...how can I do it to fit only for the internal frame?

Comment: The JDesktopPane should be initially alreayd added to the frame, as a part of the initial application (search MDI). You're probably better of just using a JDialog

Comment: Alright...will try it first :D

Comment: @peeskillet..I have tried creating a JDesktopPane and then add my JFrame into it first...when I clicked the button..then only the JDesktopPane add the internal frame...but I got an error saying java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container

Comment: :-D you need to add the desktop pane to the Jframe, not the other way around

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my previous comments. JInternalFrames are used mainly in [Multiple document interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface) programs. The desktop pane is normally part of the initial Jframe as it is opened. From there you can add internal frames to it as you please. Again, it seems to me like you mean to use a JDialog. For better help sooner, please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: hi @peeskillet, I have included the code into my post

Answer (score 1):

I don't seem to get any exceptions, attempting to create an MCVE with the code you've shown. It's not the best code, but I tried to maintain what your code looks like as much as possible. Look over it and let me know how my code differs. And again, to better help us get down to the root of the problem, you should always post an MCVE. That means the code should be runnable, i.e copy,paste,compile,run.

And also please consider all my above comments (i.e. maybe using a JDialog, if you don't plan to make this application an MDI (see the link in comment) type application.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MainUser implements ActionListener {

    WindowConstruct wconstruct;

    JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
    JInternalFrame InternalWindows = new JInternalFrame();

    public MainUser() {
        wconstruct = new WindowConstruct("..:: User's Helpdesk Main Page ::..",
                500, 500);
        wconstruct.add(desktop);
        wconstruct.btnNew.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object src = e.getSource();
        if (src == wconstruct.btnNew) {
            InternalWindows.setSize(500, 300);
            InternalWindows.setTitle("New task");
            InternalWindows.setLayout(null);
            InternalWindows.setClosable(true);
            InternalWindows.setLocation(100, 50);
            desktop.add(InternalWindows);
            InternalWindows.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainUser();
            }
        });
    }

    class WindowConstruct extends JFrame {
        JButton btnNew = new JButton("Add New");

        public WindowConstruct(String title, int width, int height) {
            super(title);
            setSize(width, height);
            add(btnNew, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use ur code and grab wat I can...when i clicked on the btnNew...nothing come out

Comment: the exact code is running though @_@ i will update my latest code and let u check

Comment: Was that your complete update? You changed two lines. Sorry but I don't think I can help you if you don't give me something I actually _run_ and test.

Comment: found the problem...i setLayout(null) for the wconstruct...once i taken it off...the internal frame can show...but when i move the internal frame over the buttons, they will be gone...and i have to click on them to make them appear again

Comment: Don't use null layouts/setBounds, period. If you want further help, I'm going to need something to run.

Comment: I have uploaded the wconstruct file for your referrence.